# Maximum number of screenshots allowed for App Store submission

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, screenshot

I am doing research to find out the requirements for metadata needed to submit an app to the iOS app store.

I can't find any info into the number of screenshots allowed when submitting, without signing up for the Apple Developer Program.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: You can check [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At least 1 and max 5 for each supported device (iPad, iPhone 6, iPhone6+, etc..)

You can find all the details here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html

Comment: Thanks so much. Just what I needed.

Comment: If there is 1 needed for each supported device; do we have to prepare more than one, 5 or more images?

Answer (score 12):

As of May 2018, the maximum number of screenshots per device is now 10.

Comment: Do you have a link or something to support this?

Comment: what is minimum number

Answer (score 3):

You can upload up to 5 images (1 mandatory and 4 optional) + optional 1 video file.

You can upload different screenshots per device (e.g. some 5 for iphone5s, other 5 for iPhone6 and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Now it’s easier than ever to deliver your screenshots and app preview using iTunes Connect. Just submit one set of screenshots and one optional app preview for the largest device size within a device family, and they will be used across all localizations and display sizes.
If your app’s UI or behavior changes based on device size, or if you would like to include localized screenshots, you can use the new Media Manager to add custom screenshots.